# Ruby using count to tally instances of a word instead of its component letters

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to tally up the number of wins a team has, but my code has it counting the instances of each individual letter in the team's name.

```
wins = 0  

puts "Please enter a team name to check"   

teamname = gets.chomp.to_s

tencentbeernight = IO.readlines("winners.txt").to_s

wins = tencentbeernight.count(teamname)

printf "The %2s have won %2i times" % [teamname, wins]
```

How do I get it to count the name of the team?

Comment: Unrelated, but canonical Ruby code uses `_` to separate words in variable names, e.g., `team_name` or `ten_cent_beer_night`. Please either use that (preferred) or *something* to avoid word smashes.

Comment: `gets` and `chomp` returns strings, so `to_s` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` counts the number of individual characters, not the instances of the string.

Try:

```
wins = tencentbeernight.scan(teamname).length
```

This will use `teamname` as a *regular expression* and count the number of times it appears.

Comment: IO.readLines returns an array so I believe count would return the number of elements?

Comment: @WaynePhipps - He calls ".to_s" on it so it comes back as a string representation of the Array.

Comment: well spotted, my bad

Comment: Thanks a ton, that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the array returned by [IO::readlines](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-readlines) to a string and then counting the number of times a string appears in that string can be made to work but it is not an approach that any experienced Rubiest would take.

First, let's create a file `"winners.txt"`.

```
arr = ["Raiders", "Bears", "bearskin rug", "Chargers", "my bugbears", "bears"]
str = arr.join("\n")
  #=> "Raiders\nBears\nbearskin rug\nChargers\nmy bugbears\nbears"
filename = "winners.txt"
File.write(filename, str)
  #=> 53 (characters written)
```

and get the name of the team:

```
team = gets.chomp
  #=> "bears"
```

See [IO#write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-write).<sup>1</sup>

The approach advocated in the question and provided in another answer is as follows:

```
array = IO.readlines(filename)
  #> ["Raiders\n", "Bears\n", "bearskin rug\n", "Chargers\n", "my bugbears\n", "bears"]
str = array.to_s
  #=> "[\"Raiders\\n\", \"Bears\\n\", \"bearskin rug\\n\", \"Chargers\\n\", \"my bugbears\\n\", \"bears\"]"
a = str.scan(team)
  #=> ["bears", "bears", "bears"]
a.size
  #=> 3
```

which is incorrect. We could get around those problems, but the more conventional approach is the following:

```
team = gets.downcase.chomp
  #=> "bears"

a = File.readlines(filename)
  #=> ["raiders\n", "bears\n", "bearskin rug\n", "chargers\n", "my bugbears\n", "bears"]
a.count { |s| s.downcase.match?(/\b#{team}\b/) }
  #=> 2
```

which gives the correct answer, as `a[1]` and `a[-1]` (and only those elements) are matched. The regular expression reads, "match a [word break](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) following by the value of `team` followed by another word break".

We can improve on this however. There is no need to create the temporary array, `a`. Instead we use [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach), which reads the file line-by-line and, when used without a block, returns an enumerator:

```
enum = File.foreach(filename)
  #=> #<Enumerator: File:foreach("winners.txt")>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by `enum` by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["raiders\n", "\n", "bears\n", "\n", "bearskin rug\n", "\n", "chargers\n",
  #    "\n", "my bugbears\n", "\n", "bears\n"]
```

Continuing,

```
enum.count { |s| s.downcase.match?(/\b#{team}\b/) }
  #=> 2
```

One would normally chain the two methods:

```
File.foreach(filename).count { |s| s.downcase.match?(/\b#{team}\b/) }
  #= 2
```

<sup>1 I've used `File` as the receiver for some methods that are defined in the class `IO`. That's commonly done and works because `File.superclass #=> IO`.</sup>